# How to import anonymous functions in ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

In ES6, we can import exported modules like this:

```
import { Abc } from './file-1';  // here Abc is a named export
import Def from './file-2';  // here Def is the default export
```

But how can we import anonymous functions? Consider this code:

file-3.js:

```
export function() {
  return 'Hello';
}

export function() {
  return 'How are you doing?';
}
```

How can I import above two functions in another file, given that neither are they default exports nor are they named exports (anonymous functions don't have names!)?

Comment: You can't do this.

Comment: You put them in different files.

Comment: file-3.js is syntactically invalid.

Comment: Why would you even want to do it? What's the [real problem](http://xyproblem.info) you're trying to solve?

Comment: @Ry︁: Why is `file-3.js` syntactically invalid?

Comment: @maverick: Because it’s trying to use the named export syntax without names. You have `export let name = …`, `export const name = …`, `export function name …`, `export class name …`, and `export default …`. There’s no anonymous non-default export.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Single anonymous function can be exported as `default` (default export value can be anything). *Multiple* anonymous functions cannot be exported from a module - so they cannot be imported, too.

`export` statement follows [strict syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export) that supports either named or default exports. This will result in syntax error:

```
export function() {
  return 'Hello';
}
```

These functions should be named exports:

```
export const foo = function () {
  return 'Hello';
}

export const bar = function () {
  return 'How are you doing?';
}
```

So they can be imported under same names.

Comment: `Anonymous functions cannot be exported from a module` unless default.